# How to apply mutate based on ntile()-groups in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have tried finding answers based on similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186644/r-dplyr-conditional-mutate-based-on-groups)

Being absolutely new to `tidyverse`, I have the following question: how can I estimate a median per `ntile()` using `dplyr`

```
# Data    
library(survival)
data(lung)
```

First

```
p <- lung %>% mutate(test=ntile(inst,3))
```

So now that

```
table(p$test)

 1  2  3 
76 76 75
```

I would like to estimate the median time, ie `p$time`, per `p$test`

Something like

```
p %>% mutate(test=ntile(inst,3), test.time=median(time[test %in% 1:3]))
```

Which did not provide what I sought.

Comment: You already have the groups now you just need to calculate [median per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198442/how-to-calculate-mean-median-per-group-in-a-dataframe-in-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the 'test' as a grouping variable to calculate the `median` of 'time'

```
library(dplyr)
lung %>% 
  group_by(test = ntile(inst, 3)) %>%
  mutate(test.time=median(time))
```

If a summarised output is needed, then replace `mutate` with `summarise`

Comment: Thank you @akrun, that did it. Can you briefly explain how I know that `median(time)` written in that last line refers to "test", which was created in second line? I mean why did it not estimate the median(time) based on any other variabel?

Comment: @cmirian It is only grouping by the  `test` variable created in `group_by` and the 'time' here is using the only the rows of time for each 'test' group