# How to plot a median value of a continuous parameter using dplyr or ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to plot a median time denoted `ee$rfs` per `ee$Ki67`, which is marker of many cells that proliferates in a tumor sample, ie. a continuous covariate too.

I have attached my data `ee` below. I am searching for a solution in either `dplyr` or `ggplot`. Obviously, I have sought for help, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030885/how-to-apply-mutate-based-on-ntile-groups-in-dplyr), but without luck.

My current plot:

[image]

With the following

```
ggplot(ee, (aes(x=Ki67,y=rfs))) + 

  geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(WHO)),size=6,shape=20,alpha=0.5) +
  facet_wrap(.~EOR)
```

I have tried variations of `mutate`, `group_by`, `filter` and `geom_line`. I tried `geom_smooth` but I am concerned that this draws the best fit (?) and not the median.

```
ee <- structure(list(rfs = c(26.4, 84, 42, 13.2, 18, 33.6, 39.6, 9.6, 
16.8, 19.2, 10.8, 7.2, 10.8, 76.8, 58.8, 31.2, 18, 182.4, 20.4, 
13.2, 8.4, 2.4, 123.6, 60, 100.8, 82.8, 12, 60, 18, 29.8, 68.3, 
27.2, 18.7, 64.9, 6.5, 50.3, 46.4, 29.9, 31.4, 42.7, 31.1, 98.1, 
80.9, 24.1, 49.2, 12.2, 20.5, 62.8, 9, 69, 30, 91.79, 8.57, 60.88, 
11.5, 56.87, 49.05, 16.95, 4.5, 8.74, 60.06, 37.85, 90.12, 123.76, 
47.41, 55.92, 3.09, 27.34, 4.99, 28.06, 26.71, 23.03, 6.34, 79.34, 
2.5, 19.32, 9.23, 2.6, 4.34, 45.9, 29.34, 8.58, 29.41, 30.72, 
15.97, 37.06, 17.05, 14.29, 5.95, 3.42, 60.58, 19.81, 72.91, 
16.99, 7.29, 74.32, 3.35, 39.95, 4.4, 15.44, 2.5, 28.32, 40.15, 
57.69, 27.86, 21.59, 10.09, 8.18, 21.59, 3.19, 3.12, 8.25, 14, 
14, 2, 23, 15, 9, 9, 28, 14, 23, 21, 26, 24, 63, 25, 34, 26.83333333, 
32.4, 28.76666667, 32.93333333, 32.16666667, 10.06666667, 46.66666667, 
58.06666667, 29.06666667, 30.33333333, 26.56666667, 24.23333333, 
36.5, 31.73333333, 5.733333333, 44.16666667, 46.93333333, 48.5, 
64.7, 37.16666667, 21.56666667, 14.8, 53.83333333, 59.06666667, 
8.7, 13.43333333, 12.56666667, 65.73333333, 54.83333333, 30.63333333, 
5, 65, 7, 12, 14, 6, 15, 36, 99, 16, 87, 6, 33, 3, 3, 11, 24, 
24, 15, 10, 28, 18, 14, 29, 20, 12, 42, 31, 14, 18, 29, 39, 62, 
62, 46), Ki67 = c(25, 15, 8, 15, 18, 5, 2, 18, 6, 12, 12, 13, 
13, 15, 20, 3, 30, 10, 18, 20, 7, 17, 5, 3, 20, 5, 20, 10, 2, 
5, 4, 7, 8, 12, 40, 17, 3, 5, 20, 5, 22, 6, 6, 18, 15, 12, 15, 
5, 15, 15, 3, 4, 10, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 7, 4, 2, 4, 3, 20, 15, 
25, 20, 10, 15, 15, 8, 15, 8, 8, 10, 22, 18, 50, 30, 30, 45, 
50, 30, 8, 25, 25, 10, 25, 20, 15, 10, 8, 55, 10, 10, 10, 20, 
30, 5, 20, 8, 30, 10, 15, 25, 30, 38, 15, 30, 25, 15, 5, 8, 35, 
9, 14, 2, 1, 1, 20, 30, 2, 8, 2, 16, 20, 23, 4.5, 2.2, 9.43, 
8.95, 6.47, 1.81, 7.27, 12.4, 7.97, 21.99, 8.98, 17.3, 8, 15, 
15, 20, 6, 5, 12.5, 3, 20, 20, 11.5, 2.66, 14.7, 9.13, 5, 5, 
12, 11, 2, 8, 20, 50, 10, 15, 30, 8, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 
10, 13, 10, 15, 10, 10, 40, 10, 5, 15, 15, 15, 25, 15, 30, 30, 
8, 30, 15, 20, 13), EOR = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), WHO = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-193L))
```

Comment: Actually, i'm not really sure what median you want to plot exactly. Are you trying to get one median `rfs` value for each unique value of `Ki76`? What should the resulting plot look like exactly?

Comment: Are you simply trying to indicate the median value of rfs by WHO, Ki67, and EOR in the plot you provided? Or are you trying to plot only the median value? Or are you after something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know how the median of rfs varies with Ki67 (instead of the mean in linear regression), you need to use a quantile regression.

Luckily this is implemented in ggplot2, I first make a plot without the facet to show that the regression line is very similar for the two facets:

```
library(quantreg)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ee,aes(x=Ki67,y=rfs)) + 
geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(WHO)),alpha=0.5) +
geom_quantile(aes(linetype=factor(EOR)),quantiles = 0.5,col="black")
```

[image]

And having the facet (you don't need to specify group):

```
ggplot(ee,aes(x=Ki67,y=rfs)) + 
geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(WHO)),alpha=0.5) +
geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.5,lty=8,col="black")+
facet_wrap(.~EOR)
```

[image]

Or you can derive the predictions per group, and plot:

```
func = function(df,X,id){
  fit = rq(rfs ~ Ki67,data=df)
  data.frame(Ki67=X,rfs=predict(fit,data.frame(Ki67=X)))
}

Xrange= 1:max(ee$Ki67)

pred = ee %>% group_by(EOR) %>% group_map(~func(.x,Xrange)) %>% bind_rows()
pred$EOR = rep(unique(ee$EOR),each=length(Xrange))

ggplot(ee,aes(x=Ki67,y=rfs)) + 
geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(WHO)),alpha=0.5) +
geom_line(data=pred)+
    facet_wrap(.~EOR)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to plot the median rfs value by WHO, Ki67, and EOR, then you can use `group_by` and `summarise`, and feed the summarised data to `ggplot`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ee %>%
  group_by(WHO, Ki67, EOR) %>%
  summarise(rfs = median(rfs)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Ki67, y = rfs, color = factor(WHO))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ EOR)
```

[image]